# Make computer choose between 2 paths in batch

Tags: batch-file

How do I get the code below to choose a random path?

```
@echo off
   
echo Hello

:a
echo Madam
goto end

:b
echo Sir

:end
```

So the program needs to choose between a or b randomly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since `%random%` gives you a random number between `0` and `32767`, you could use something like:

```
    @echo off
    if %random% lss 16384 goto :option2
:option1
    echo Hello, madam.
    goto :optionend
:option2
    echo Hello, sir.
:optionend
    rem Rest of code
```